# How can I replace special characters from string with PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have folowing string:

```
a&b.c'd,e f
```

How do I look like

```
а_b_c_d_e_f
```

How look like the regex pattern?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: you can use \W => ([\W])

Comment: What characters do you want to allow? Eg lowercase, uppercase, numbers, underscores...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will look as simple as...

```
$str = "a&b.c'd,e f";
$str = preg_replace('#\W#', '_', $str);
```

... but it should actually depend on what characters *you* consider special, as `\W` is equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` (i.e., anything that is not alphanumeric or '_'). It may or may not be sufficient in your case; if not, perhaps you'd just use a character class here:

```
$str = "a&b.c'd,e f";
$str = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]#', '_', $str);
```

In this example hyphen `'-'` won't be replaced as well.

Answer (score 1):

With [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$regex = "(.*)\W(.*)";
$content = "a&b.c'd,e f"
preg_replace($regex, "_", $content);
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? It won't work for two reasons: no regex delimiters, first, wrong modifier syntax, second. And even if it was written correct, the regex itself is wrong: the whole string will be replaced by a single `'_'` with it.

Comment: I wrote it from memory without testing, yes. I don't have access to my server at the minute. On the bright side, the link works.